# How to denote a set that contains elements of its elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say I have a set $S_1$, which contains elements $A, B, C$ which also could contain other sets or other numbers.

How would I represent a set $S_2$ such that it contains all of the elements of the elements of $S_1$, (and all of their elements... etc).

**For example:**

How would I get $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$ from $\left\{1,2,\left\{3,4,\left\{5,6\right\}\right\}\right\}$?

Comment: So, for example, if you have the set $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ you want to know how to represent $\{1,2,3,4\}$, or do you want to represent $\{1,2,3,4,\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$?

Comment: This is different from the power set. The term you want is "transitive closure".

Comment: @Dave Actually the first example you made is more reasonable for my cause. I'll be more specific in the question.

Comment: As for your example, you could recursively partition your given set into singletons, and then take the union of these singletons. So, if $S_1:=\{1,2,\{3,4,\{5,6\}\}\}$ then we partition into $$\left(\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4,\{5,6\}\}\right)$$then partition $\{3,4,\{5,6\}\}$ into $$\left(\{3\},\{4\},\{5,6\}\right)$$and so on.

Comment: @Dave Ah okay, that helps.

Comment: The problem is that for set theorists numbers are usually also sets. For example, $3=\{0,1,2\}=\{0,\{0\},\{0,1\}\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$. So you have to specify where to stop with your prodcedure.

Comment: @CarstenS Well that makes things a bit more complicated then

Comment: Wath do you mean by "represent"? In Mathematica the function $\texttt{Flatten[]}$ will do the job.

Comment: @Somos I guess by means of representation I mean a general function or notation that will describe what I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a universal set of elements $U$. For example, $U=\{1,2,3,\dots\}.$ Define recursively $\forall x\in U \;f(x):=\{x\},\;$ otherwise $f(S):=\bigcup_{x\in S} f(x).$ Examples, $f(3)=\{3\},$ $f(\{3,4\})=\{3,4\},\;$ $f(\{2,\{3,4\}\})=\{2,3,4\},\;$
 $f(\{1,2,\{3,4,\{5,6\}\}\})\!=\!\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Mathematica implementation ($\texttt{Flatten[]}$ doesn't work on atoms) could be:

```
f[x_] := {x} /; MemberQ[U, x];
f[x_List] := Union @@ Table[f[e], {e, x}];
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly work. Example: $f( \{ 1, \{1\} \}) = f(1) \cup f(\{1\}) = 1 \cup f(\{1\})$ but how would we now make sense of $1 \cup a$?

Answer (score 0):

To define this operation in a useful way, you need to have a specified class $\mathbb{A}$ of things that you want to consider as being 'not sets'. In your example, $\mathbb{A}$ contains (at least) the natural numbers $1$ through $6$. I'll leave foundational issues aside for the moment. In this case, the set $S_2$ that you seek can be defined by
$$S_2 = \{ a \in \mathbb{A} \mid a \in \mathrm{trcl}(S_1) \} = \boxed{\mathbb{A} \cap \mathrm{trcl}(S_1)}$$
where $\mathrm{trcl}(X)$ is the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure) of $X$, defined by
$$\mathrm{trcl}(X) = X \cup \bigcup X \cup \bigcup \bigcup X \cup \cdots$$
That is, $S_2$ is the set of 'things that are not sets' that appear as an element, or an element of an element, or an element of an element of an element, and so on, of $S_1$.

Now to address the foundational issues. If you push a mathematician to tell you which foundational system they're using, they'll probably tell you they're working within [ZFC set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), in which case you're in a little bit of trouble because in that system, everything is a set (including the natural numbers). I'm sure there are work-arounds to find a meaningful answer to your question within ZFC, but it's a little bit tricky: for instance, you can't just take $\mathbb{A}=\mathbb{N}$ in your example, since under the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_construction) construction of the natural numbers, if $S_1 = \{ 3 \}$ (for example) then you'd have $S_2 = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ by virtue of the fact that $0 \in 1 \in 2 \in 3$. I'm sure there's a workaround within ZFC, but it would require a lot more thought.

However, there are set theories which have objects which are *not* sets (called *atoms* or [*urelements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement)); in these settings, you could just take $\mathbb{A}$ to be the class of all atoms and be done with it.